# ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

After upgrading to RC5 we began getting this error:

```
ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup 
 directive.
Try using formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:

    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });

      Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control,
 indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:

      Example:

      
  <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
     <input formControlName="firstName">
     <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </div>
```

It looks like in RC5 the two can no longer be used together, but I could not find an alternative solution.

Here is the component producing the exception:

```html
    <select class="field form-control" [formGroup]="form" [(ngModel)]="cause.id" [name]="name">
    <option *ngFor="let c of causes" [value]="c.text">{{c.text}}</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Did you import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: Sure, both of them

Comment: AFAIK, the only existing explanation is the following: http://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/

Comment: Found source of the change:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10314

Answer (score 261):

The answer is right on the error message,
you need to indicate that it's standalone and therefore it doesn't conflict with the form controls:

```html
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Comment: what does standalone means?

Comment: It means that its not handled by the form model/data so you can pass data by any object/model you want as it used to be in AngularJS 1

Comment: I only see this problem in my test setup. What is exactly missing? [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" fixes test but changes logic. ngModel is inherited from parent component, that declares ngForm in my case

Comment: `Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.` [https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel](https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel)

Answer (score 37):

Expanding on @Avenir Çokaj's answer

Being a novice even I did not understand the error message clearly at first.

What the error message indicates is that in your formGroup you have an element that doesn't get accounted for in your formControl. (Intentionally/Accidentally)

If you intend on not validating this field but still want to use the ngModel on this input element please add the flag to indicate it's a standalone component without a need for validation as mentioned by @Avenir above.

Comment: What if you want to use if for validation AND use it with ngModel at the same time though?

Comment: In my case I missed out to declare formControl for an element inside formGroup !

Answer (score 20):

OK, finally got it working: see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10314#issuecomment-242218563

In brief, you can no longer use `name` attribute within a `formGroup`, and must use `formControlName` instead

Answer (score 9):

when you write **formcontrolname** Angular 2 do not accept. You have to write **formControlName** . it is about uppercase second words.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="myObject.name" formcontrolname="nameFormControl"/>
```

if the error still conitnue try to set form control for all of object(myObject) field.

between start `<form> </form>` for example: `<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm.value)"> set form control for all input field </form>.`

Answer (score 9):

This error apears when you have some form controls (like Inputs, Selects, etc) in your form group tags with no formControlName property.

Those examples throws the error:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text" [ngmodel]="nameProperty">
    <input type="text" [formGroup]="myform" [name]="name">
</fom>
```

There are two ways, the stand alone:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <input type="text" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <input type="text" [ngmodel]="nameProperty" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <!-- input type="text" [formGroup]="myform" [name]="name" --> <!-- no works with standalone --
</form>
```

Or including it into the formgroup

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
    <input type="text" formControlName="field1">
    <input type="text" formControlName="nameProperty">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
</fom>
```

The last one implies to define them in the initialization formGroup

```
this.myForm =  new FormGroup({
    field1: new FormControl(''),
    nameProperty: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl('')
});
```

Comment: Fixed my error by adding the element (toggle button )to form group that was missing.   The error message does not reveal this.   Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```js
import { FormControl, FormGroup, AbstractControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


    this.userInfoForm = new FormGroup({
      userInfoUserName: new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
      userInfoName: new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
      userInfoSurName: new FormControl({ value: '' }, Validators.compose([Validators.required]))
    });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="userInfoForm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><i>*</i> User Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="userInfoUserName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.userName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><i>*</i> Name</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="userInfoName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"><i>*</i> Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="userInfoSurName" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userInfo.surName">
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **If component has more than 1 form, register all controls and forms**

I needed to know why this was happening in a certain component and not in any other component.

The issue was that I had 2 forms in one component and the second form didn't yet have `[formGroup]` and wasn't registered yet since I was still building the forms.

I went ahead and completed writting both forms complete without leaving a input not registered which solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error because I did not enclose all my form controls within a `div` with a `formGroup` attribute.

For example, this will throw an error

```
<div [formGroup]='formGroup'>
</div>
<input formControlName='userName' />
```

This can be quite easy to miss if its a particularly long form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `[formGroup]` with `formControlName`, you must replace `name` attribute with `formControlNameformControlName`.

Example:

This does not work because it uses the `[formGroup]` and `name` attribute.

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <input name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
</div>
```

You should replace the `name` attribute by `formControlName` and it will work fine like this following:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
   <input formControlName="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName">
</div>
```

Comment: a solution for this could also be if you're using a [formGroup]="myGroup" and internally reference with [(ngModel)] a property that is nog in the formGroup.

try adding                     [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"
so you tell your compiler it may be excluded and it is a standalone property

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not importing the NgForOF and MatOptionModule, So importing them solved my problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ47q.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you really need a ngModal inside a reactive form `[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }"` will solve this