# model based forms in angular 2 rc5 not working

Tags: forms, angular, angular-rc5

I am migrating code from angular beta to RC5 version. 
and i am facing issue with the model based forms used.
As i have to much forms already developed in angular 2 beta. its hard for me to changes model based forms to template based forms.
any help in forms migration is highly appreciated.

my existing code is like this

**profile.ts**

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

 this.firstName = new FormControl();
        this.lastName = new FormControl();
        this.email = new FormControl();
        this.addressLine = new FormControl();
        this.postal = new FormControl();
        this.postalArea = new FormControl();

        this.form = builder.group({
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            email: this.email,
            addressLine: this.addressLine,
            postal: this.postal,
            postalArea: this.postalArea,
            photo: this.photo
        });
```

and template in profile.HTML is like follows

```
<form class="form-default"  [formGroup]="form">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" formControlName="firstName" maxlength="200">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" formControlName="lastName" maxlength="200">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" [(ngModel)]="model.username" readonly formControlName="email" maxlength="100">

    </form>
```

I am facing following error in console.

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in
>   /assets/scripts/my-profile/my-profile.html:176:66 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: 
>         ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
>
>   Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:
>
>   Example:
>
>
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>    <input formControlName="firstName">
>    <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Still no one is able to answer this question. really strange!!

Answer (score 5):

Here you can find the [answer to the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588951/583065) just add:

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Answer (score -1):

to have the both `ngModel` and `formControl` in your html you have to have a model in your component (e.g. `firstName` in the following example) that you bind to from your html and also you need to build a form group including your desired `formControl` (e.g. `firstNameControl` in the following example)

### component:

```
 this.firstName: string;
 this.form = builder.group({
            firstNameControl: this.firstName,                
        });
```

### html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">    
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="firstName" [formControl]="form.controls.firstNameControl"></input>
</form
```

Comment: to work with ngModel and have the formControl both on html you have to have a model in the component (e.g. firstName) and then bind to it in ngModel, the sample I have here works for me.

Comment: ok so you mean that  order does matter. Can you please rephrase your answer by emphasizing  it. because it is difficult to make out.