# Ionic 2 form validation issue with formGroup and ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was trying to implement what seemed to be a straightforward form validation routine following [this walk-through](https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/) on my ionic 2 projects.

In my controller's constructor I used the `FormBuilder` like this to make a formGroup:

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  date: ['', Validators.required],
  client: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

And then in the template I added `formControllerName` attribute to relevant elements like this:

```
<ion-select formControlName="client" [(ngModel)]="clientId">
```

And bound the root element to the 'formGroup` like this:

```
<ion-content [formGroup]="form">
```

This fails with the following error message:

> ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent
>   formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
>
>   Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:
>
>   Example:
>
>
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>    <input formControlName="firstName">
>    <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
> </div>
> ```

As suggested by the error message, as well as [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126638/ngmodel-cannot-be-used-to-register-form-controls-with-a-parent-formgroup-directi/40588951#40588951) I added `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to my inputs but it came back with another error message:

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'ion-select'.

Comment: Why are you using both `formControlName` and `ngModel`?

Comment: @Amit Does that (formControlName) also do the binding? If so could you please post an answer explaining how I can access the bound values?

Comment: Yes and I will :)

Comment: @Amit is it not possible to use both formControlName and ngModel? If you don't use ngModel, how to you map the model in typescript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular2 you can choose to either use the "old" (more AngularJS-y) template-driven way, by using `[(ngModel)]` to create two-way bindings with your component variables:

Component:

```
private clientId: string;
```

Template:

```
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="clientId" required />
</form>
```

If I got facts together, this will behind-the-scenes create a `FormGroup` instance for the `<form>` element, and a `FormControl` instance for each input in it. The required directive will then apply a validator on it and trigger validation (and for example apply ng-valid/invalid accordingly).

Using this approach you can grab the value simply using `clientId`.

Using the model-driven (or "reactive") approach is by defining the form's "schema" using `FormBuilder` or simply creating instances of `FormGroup` and `FormControl`...

It would look something like this:

Component:

```
private form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
        clientId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="clientId" />
</form>
```

In this case, if you want the entire form's value, you'd access `(this.)form.value` which in this example will return an object like this:

```
 { clientId: "whatever" }
```

Or if you only want the inner control's value, grab `(this.)form.controls['clientId'].value`.

Hope I made things clearer and not worse :)

**EDIT:**
Using the latter approach means you can access an `Observable` of the `FormControl` and do some interesting things, for example:

```
let debouncedInput$ = this.form.control['clientId'].valueChanges.debounceTime(1000);
```

Comment: Added one more edit, in my opinion this is what makes reactive forms so much better.

Comment: I did what you said but I'm getting this error now: `No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`.

Any chance you would also know what is that about?

Comment: Can you post your template and component?

Comment: this.form = formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    });

Comment: <form [formControl]="form">
  <ion-input formControlName="name" type="text"></ion-input>
</form>

Comment: Hmm, seems `<ion-input>` doesn't have a ControlValueAccessor, which seems unlikely, maybe you're on an older version of angular or ionic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137530/discussion-between-vahid-and-amit).