# form control error:ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: forms, angular

In the below component when the  component is loaded in the angular4 app I keep getting the error:

> ng:///HeaderModule/HeaderComponent.ngfactory.js:334 ERROR Error: No
> value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

I have tried removing `ngModel` and `value` attributes but nothing has worked.

I'm assuming the issue is with the header .component.html.
Below is the html

```
<!-- Notification area-->
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="changeNotificationStatus()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i>
        <span class="visible-xs-inline">Notifications</span>
        <span class="badge badge-sm up bg-danger pull-right-xs" [hidden]="notificationCount<=0" [(ngModel)]="notificationCount"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu w-xl animated fadeInUp">
</li>
```

Not sure what causes the problem.
If somebody could point out the issue it will be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error is emitted, if you forget to specify the `name`attribute for an `ngModel`.

You can find following line in your html that contains the error:

```
<span class="badge badge-sm up bg-danger pull-right-xs" [hidden]="notificationCount<=0" [(ngModel)]="notificationCount"></span>
```

As you can see, there is no `name` attribute.

Comment: In case it helps anyone: I had this error in Ionic and Google got me to this question/answer. I found the problem was that I had mistakenly put the [(ngModel)] on the ion-label instead of the ion-input.

Answer (score 29):

Use `ngDefaultControl` directive to make your form has default `2way` binding

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" ngDefaultControl>
```

Comment: This solved my problem in IONIC4, but I don't know why- I have another application which does not use `ngDefaultControl` and databinds fine.

Answer (score 4):

This error also occurs if you try to add ngModel to the non-input elements. Make sure you add ngModel only to the  tags. In my case, I have added a ngModel to the `<option>` instead of `<select>` in HTML select Tag

Comment: I thought how silly would it be to write something so trivial as an answer and than I've noticed I've done exactly that, I've accidentally placed ngModel in an <option>, thanks for pointing that out!!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this worked like this

Just added the `name="searchInput"`

Before:

```
 <input type="text" nz-input placeholder="Search Project"
        [(ngModel)]="searchInput" (ngModelChange)="search()">
```

After:

```
<input type="text" name="searchInput" nz-input placeholder="Search Project"
       [(ngModel)]="searchInput" (ngModelChange)="search()">
```

Answer (score 0):

in ionic 4 i had this error in my code:

```
<ion-label [name]="num_lable"                                       [(ngModel)]="num_temp[i]"> {{num_temp[i]}}</ion-label>
```

i changed code to:
(ngModel is Unnecessary in my code)

```
<ion-label> {{num_temp[i]}}</ion-label>
```

and now error not shown :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer specific to Angular 14+ and stand-alone components**

I realize this post is 5 years old at this point, but when I had similar issues and errors after trying to migrate to *Angular 14 stand-alone components*, this is the stack-overflow post I ended up on. So this is where I will post *my* solution.

After converting a larger projects to stand-alone components, I suddenly found errors like the one below at runtime, despite the project building just fine:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name '{some name}'

If you're in a similar situation, I found the reason, and the fix is very, very easy once you know what to look for.

Basically when I had converted my project to stand-alone components, I had gradually migrated more and more modules into stand-alone components, typically from leaf level and gradually upwards.

But for one module (for whatever reasons) I had converted it a different way.

This in turn had caused me import the wrong component into one of my new stand-alone components.

Basically I had tried to import ComponentA (which depended on SubcomponentB) when what I needed was really only SubcomponentB. This passed the compiler, but not the runtime!

*In these cases what you need to do is to look for the name which is causing runtime form-issues, and see what sub-component it has been bound to.*

Chances are this component has not been correctly imported. In my case, it wasn't. Once you ensure it's imported correctly your component, this error should go away.

Or at least it did for me. YMMV.