# What is the best practice to show Reactive Form Error Message without multiple *ngIf?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am developing job form which contains job related fields and some of the fields have more than 5 validation.

Here is my Html Code:

```html
<div [formGroup]="jobForm">
  <div>
<input type="text" formControlName="userName"/>
    <div *ngIf="jobForm.controls.userName.errors && jobForm.controls.userName.errors.required"
    class="alert alert-danger">
      Required....
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="jobForm.controls.userName.errors && jobForm.controls.userName.errors.maxLength"
    class="alert alert-danger">
      max length 10
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="jobForm.controls.userName.errors && jobForm.controls.userName.errors.exits"
    class="alert alert-danger">
      user is already exits
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="jobForm.controls.userName.errors && jobForm.controls.userName.errors.shouldNotSameAsName"
    class="alert alert-danger">
      Should Not Same as name.
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="jobForm.controls.userName.errors && jobForm.controls.userName.errors.minLength"
    class="alert alert-danger">
      minimum length is 5
    </div>
</div>
```

In my job form there are more than 15 fields in one wizard, It is bit difficult to manage the code on HTML side with *ngIf conditions. How can I overcome this problem?

See the below link, which is little bit same as mine but it is not marked as answer and not found any documentation on the provided answer.

[Best way to show error messages for angular reactive forms, one formcontrol multiple validation errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771445/best-way-to-show-error-messages-for-angular-reactive-forms-one-formcontrol-mult)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can store the error message and key's in the TS file and use that to display in HTML

Comment: how can I, can you please share some code. That would be great for me.

Comment: Hi Check this: https://netbasal.com/angular-clean-up-your-form-template-646faa164b1b

Comment: Thanks for this, I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has answered this question and my issue was resolved with the provided answer. But that has been removed, I don't know why.

I have used [@rxweb/reactive-form-validators](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators) for showing error message without *ngIf.

I have used 'RxFormBuilder' to create a FormGroup object and used errorMessage property of FormControl.
Below is the TS code which I have downloaded form the provided answer:

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  userFormGroup:FormGroup;

 

  constructor(private formBuilder:RxFormBuilder){}

 

 

  ngOnInit(){

  //this is used for to configure validation message globally. https://www.rxweb.io/api/reactive-form-config

    ReactiveFormConfig.set({

     "validationMessage":{

    "required":"This field is required",

      "minLength":"minimum length is {{0}}",

      "maxLength":"allowed max length is {{0}}"

      }

    });

 

    this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

     userName:['',[RxwebValidators.required(),RxwebValidators.minLength({value:5}),RxwebValidators.maxLength({value:10})]]

    })

  }
```

Html Code :

```html
<form [formGroup]="userFormGroup">

<div class="form-group">

    <label>UserName</label>

    <input type="text" formControlName="userName" class="form-control"  />

    {{userFormGroup.controls.userName["errorMessage"]}}

 

</div>

</form>
```