# Angular Reactive Form Control Errors: how to read the error object

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a number of custom validators that will apply to fields in a dynamically generated Reactive Form in Angular 7.

The template looks like this:

```html
<ng-container class="table-wrapper" *ngIf="!field.hide && field.display === fieldTypes.get('Text')">
  <label>
    <span class="form-label">{{field.label}}</span>
    <span *ngIf="dynForm.controls[field.name].invalid
    && ( dynForm.controls[field.name].dirty || dynForm.controls[field.name].touched )">
      {{errorMessageResolver(field, dynForm.controls[field.name].errors)}}
    </span>
  </label>
  <input type="text" name="{{field.name}}" value="{{field.val}}" formControlName="{{field.name}}"/>
</ng-container>
```

As you can see, I have a function that pulls out the generated ValidationError from the form and feeds it into the following function:

```js
  errorMessageResolver(field: Field, errors: ValidationErrors) {
    console.log('valids=' + field.validations.length);
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(errors as ValidationErrors);
    console.log(errors.hasOwnProperty('required'));
    console.log(errors.hasOwnProperty('minLength'));
    console.log(errors.minLength);
    console.log(errors.hasOwnProperty('maxLength'));
  }
```

The result of the extensive console logging is:
[image]

As I hope you can see, the minLength ValidationError is definitely being picked up, because you can see the console output:

```
{ minLength: {...}}
```

But the following attempted consoles should show how there doesn't seem to be a way to get hold of the actual value. So how do you get hold of the key and its value?

Comment: It's minlength with lowercase L. I hope that's not what's confusing you.

Comment: you can use 'errorMessage' property in the html form, refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920271/what-is-the-best-practice-to-show-reactive-form-error-message-without-multiple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Angular Forms do not provide validation messages/values. They are very simple objects that simply display the name of each `Validator` attached to the `FormControl` whose requirements the `<input>` does not meet.

So when the `minLength` error exists, that means that the validator returned invalid, otherwise you will not see `minLength` in the errors object at all.

In your example you provide the `<input>` element with a `formControlName` of `field.name`. You should be able to access the errors via this `FormControl's` [errors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors) property in your method like:

```
if(errors['required']) {
    // The required validator returned invalid
}
```

Or by using the [hasError](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasError) method on the `FormControl` like so:

```
if(this.form.get(field.name).hasError('required')) {
    // The required validator returned invalid
}
```

Just to make you aware, the reason `errors.minLength` returns `undefined` is because the `error` object is a type that looks like this: `{ [key: string]: any; }` i.e. it is an [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types). The property accessor fails because it really doesn't have a property called `minLength`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: even getting hold of the name would be ok actually, because I could use it to then return my error messages. Other than JSON.stringify(), nothing seems to work to even get the key: "minLength"

Comment: Understood, please see my edit for more details. Hopefully it helps.