# how do I figure out which validator to give an error in form-control

Tags: angular

In a component with an input, I pass an array of such objects for validation:

```
export class ValidatorItem {
    validator: ValidatorFn;
    errorText: string;
}
```

in component:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('validators' in changes) {
      this.formModel = this.formBuilder.group({
        value: ['', Validators.compose(this.validators.map(v => v.validator))],
      });
    }
 }
```

that is, I need to get an errorText message depending on which validator fell. How can i do this?

Comment: Please go through this link. [Validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771445/best-way-to-show-error-messages-for-angular-reactive-forms-one-formcontrol-mult)

Comment: A validator is a function that return null (if all is Ok) or, generally, an object if there're an error. you simply ask about one property of this object. e.g. Validators.email return an object `{email:'error'}`, Validators.required return an object `{required:true}`and so on. so you ask about `control.errors?.email` or about `control.errors?.required`.