# No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

Hey iam Databinding my slider to an attribute whit the values 1 and 0. On 1 the switch should be active, on 0 it shouldnt. I successfully Databinded some Input and Select Elements but at the Slider i run into following error:

> No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

This is my HTML part:

```
<div class="slidercontainer aftericn">
   Off
   <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="endless" #ctrl="ngModel" name="endless" 
   id="endless"></mat-slide-toggle>
   On
</div>
```

I do not have any Form arround it, and i also have a name attribute, so i dont understand why this error happens! Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

Here is the whole Mat-Card Block:

```
  <mat-card class="inputdatacard">
     <div class="flexcontainercolumn">
        <div class="flexcontainerrow">
           <div>
              <mat-icon class="suffixicon" aria-label="person">today
              </mat-icon>
           </div>
           <div class="flexcontainerrow100">
              <label>Endlos</label>
              <div class="slidercontrainer">
                 Off
                 <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="endless" [(ngModel)]="endless" name="endless" id="endless"></mat-slide-toggle>
                 On
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <mat-form-field class="startdatecont" [(ngModel)]="startdate">
           <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Startdatum" [value]="startdate">
           <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
           <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>

         <mat-form-field *ngIf="endless == 0" class="enddatecont">
           <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Enddatum">
           <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
           <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
     </div>
  </mat-card>
```

**EDIT 2**

Added [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfrn2u) (Error shows up in Console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by simple deleting and inserting the element. Seems like this is a bit bugged. Got the same problem whit form-field-control error. Deleteing and Inserting it solved the Issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but in my case apparently it was a synchronization issue, at the moment of render the components html.

I followed some of the solutions proposed on this page but any of them worked for me, at least not completely.

What did actually solve my error was to write the below code snippet inside the father html tag of the elements

I was binding to the variable.

Code:

```
    *ngIf="variable-name"
```

The error was caused, apparently by the project trying to render the page, apparently at the moment of evaluating the variable, the project just could no find its value. With the above code snippet you make sure that before rendering the page you ask if the variable has being initialized.

Comment: Thank´s for the editing marc_s, sorry for the trouble, english is not my mother languaje.

Answer (score 0):

[**This blitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvpfu5?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.html) works well with your code, are you sure you didn't do something else ?

By the way, one binding will be enough.

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="endless" name="endless" id="endless"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

Comment: Hmm i dont think so, cause its working on my input and select elements. Also the Slider shows proberly and is binded to my value. Maybe a bug? Cause the error doesnt effect the functions?

Comment: Or maybe your error doesn't come from that ? (And you don't think so, but I assure you, one binding is enough)

Comment: Yeah i have changed it to one binding. Error comes from line 294 in this html file, wich is exactly the line whit the mat slide toggle.

Comment: Could you give the whole HTML ?

Comment: sure i have added it to my post

Comment: Well sorry, but I don't see any issue in your code ... Maybe make a [mcve] on Stackblitz ?

Comment: [Blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfrn2u) In my Case, the error also occurs in stackblitz. (on development console)