# Why I get error message when try pass reference on HTML element?

Tags: angular, angular8

I get this message:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

HTML is:

```
<div>
  <input #input type="text" name="input" />
  <div range [formControl]="input" [classCss]="'close_btn'">Select</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems `input` is not a formcontrol. seems to be a template reference `#input`

Comment: change [formControl]="input" to something else, or to some other name

Comment: Try out the solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422007/error-error-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified-name-attribute?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value from input filed use it like this : -

```
<input name="name" ngModel id="someId" placeholder="Enter some data" type="text" class="form-control" required>
```

OR

```
<input name="name" [(ngModel)] = "name" id="someId" placeholder="Enter some data" type="text" class="form-control" required>
```