# How to Display List of Data from Typescript to Html in Ionic-Angular?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I'm getting the list of values I needed from the console log but I don't know how to output it on my view. Can someone help me please.

Here's my typescript file:

```
 customFunction(val: any) {
    this.modifiedText = val + " was selected from the dropdown";
    let id = val;
    this.pokeService.getGenerationSpecies(id).subscribe((details) => {
      this.species = Object.values(details);
      this.pokemonSpecies = Object.values(this.species[6]);
      let iterator = this.pokemonSpecies.values();
      for (let elements of iterator) {
        console.log("result:", elements.name);
      }
    });
  }
```

And I would like to output the elements.name results here:

```
  <ion-item>
      <ion-label [(ngModel)]="customFunction"><b>{{elements.name}}</b></ion-label
      >
    </ion-item>
```

Edited:

Here's my service for reference:

```
  getGenerationSpecies(index) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/generation/${index}?limit=25`).pipe(
      map((species) => {
        let pokemonSpecies = Object.keys(species);
        species["id"] = pokemonSpecies.filter((id) => id);
        console.log("species:", species);
        return species;
      })
    );
  }
```

Can someone show me the correct way please. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `*ngFor` to iterate through every item in your list `elements.name`, since you mention that is a list. In that case, what is happening now is that you get the whole list and try to print it at once.

Could look like this (haven't tested it):

```
<ion-item *ngFor='let name of elements.names'>
  <ion-label .... >{{ name }}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let element of pokemonSpecies.values()">
  <!-- depending on what you went to send to your customFunction, change the parameter -->
  <ion-label [(ngModel)]="customFunction(element)"><b>{{element.name}}</b></ion-label
  >
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. This code works for me but I'm getting a loop of console log error saying "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"  then my app crashed after a few minutes in the browser. @João

Comment: @Xev That have to do with your form take a look in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422007/error-error-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified-name-attribute/54755671
Or edit your question to contain more informaiton of you HTML and component.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

In `your.component.ts`:

```
    export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    
      elements: any;
    
      constructor(
      ) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      customFunction(val: any) {
        this.modifiedText = val + " was selected from the dropdown";
        let id = val;
        this.pokeService.getGenerationSpecies(id).subscribe((details) => {
        this.species = Object.values(details);
        this.pokemonSpecies = Object.values(this.species[6]);
        this.elements = this.pokemonSpecies.values();
      });
    }
    
}
```

In your `your.component.html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of elements, let i=index">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label><b>{{item.name}}</b></ion-label
      >
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

In `your.service.ts` add return type `Observable<any>`:

```
getGenerationSpecies(index): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/generation/${index}?limit=25`).pipe(
      map((species) => {
        let pokemonSpecies = Object.keys(species);
        species["id"] = pokemonSpecies.filter((id) => id);
        console.log("species:", species);
        return species;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not getting any data even when I log it in the console.

Comment: so you can't get any data from details in `this.pokeService.getGenerationSpecies(id).subscribe((details) => { ... })` right ?

Comment: if you can't get any data from calling service you need to provide the service component that you call in your question, so we can help you

Comment: Yes I'm having some hard time accessing the property from my service, that's why I just tried to get it from my customFuction. By the way, the service component is already added on my post. Thanks