# Pass a ngModel from a Child Component to a Parent Component containing the ngForm

Tags: angular

I'am trying to create a ngForm on a `parent-component` where I have a `child-component` with a ngModel on an input, I want my ngForm to get the value of the ngModel.

This is the error.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'InputName'
```

[Link to StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pyzdpj)

*Let me know if you need anything else.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add 'ngDefaultControl' to your child where you have the ngModel attribute, and it works fine.

```
<child [name]="'InputName'" [type]="'text'" ngModel ngDefaultControl></child>
```

For detailed explanations please refer below:

1. [What is ngDefaultControl in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46465891/what-is-ngdefaultcontrol-in-angular/46465959)
2. [ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute on switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422007/error-error-no-value-accessor-for-form-control-with-unspecified-name-attribute)