# Create a component to show input counter (Angular 8)

Tags: angular

I have to show the input characters counter several times in distinct components. So I thought it was best to create a component for it.

Example:

[image: input counter]

I have tried to make a template reference variable and show its value. However, the count isn't dynamic. It stays static. Here's the live example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-26eg4z).

The code is very simple:

app.component.html

```
<input type="text" #input>
<app-caracter-counter [input]="input.value.length"></app-caracter-counter>
```

And the code of the component I created:

caracter-count.component.ts

```
export class CaracterCounterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() input:number;
}
```

This was the simplest way I found, but doesn't work.

I tried binding an event emmitter, but that would require to use the @Output in all components that I use this `caracter-counter`.

Is there any way to make this component works using only template tags (in the component that I'll be using the `caracter-counter`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answers has been posted before. Here a little improvement, in case you are using **formControlName** inside a **formGroup** in a **ReactiveForms** scenario than you neither need to use templateAccess variable nor ngModel. Here is a sample code

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
<input type="text" formControlName="txtCtrl1" />
</form>
<app-caracter-counter [input]="myFormGroup.get('txtCtrl1').value.length"></app-caractercounter>
```

Please find the working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjimec).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngModel` to create a two way binding from your input field to a AppComponent property, then pass that property to your child component:

[Created a blitzstack for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gn9zt2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

In your app.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="text">

<div *ngIf="text.length !== 0">
    <app-caracter-counter [input]="text.length"></app-caracter-counter>
</div>
```

In your app.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  text: string = '';
}
```

Comment: I cannot add ngModel because an error is trigered: "ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead." and doesn't work

Comment: `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`, add this to your input, you can read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126638/ngmodel-cannot-be-used-to-register-form-controls-with-a-parent-formgroup-directi

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="true" (change)="true" #textInput>
<div *ngIf="textInput.value.length !== 0">
 <app-caracter-counter [input]="textInput.value.length"></app-caracter-counter> 
</div>
```

I added `(keyup)="true" (change)="true"` and change your condition to `textInput.value.length !== 0` (instead of `===`)

You don't need to do that when using input with forms since you have `ngModel` or `formControlName`

Comment: Your code works, thank you! But I have a question. I'm using fromControlName. Does that change anything?

Comment: yes, if you use formControlName you don't need to add the event handlers